# How to run mocha script to test url via browser (without using XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

Hello: though new to nodejs and mocha and seek your help. Thank You in advance.

I am trying to run a simple mocha test via the browser (not the terminal) to access a url and get the response status.

Using `XMLHttpRequest` it works. However, i want to use a node library (say [request.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)). For testing mocha script from browser i am unable to find how load request.js correctly. Please help.

**test.js (using XMLHttpRequest)**

```
describe('suite', function(){

    it('case using XMLHTTPREQUEST', function(done){        
        var url = "http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/test_files/formula_stress_test_ajax.xlsx";
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log("TEST RESPONSE STATUS IS: " + xhr.status);
        }
        xhr.send();
        done();
    });

    it('case using AXIOS', function(done){        
        axios.get('http://www.google.com').then(
            function(response){
                    console.log(response.status);
                    done();
            });
    });
});
```

**testrunner.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Mocha Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>
  <script src="../node_modules/axios/dist/axios.js"></script>
  <script src="../node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script>mocha.setup('bdd')</script>
  <script src="./test.js"></script>
  <script>
    mocha.run()
  </script>
</body>    
</html>
```

Comment: request.js module many not work with browsers. Try using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) instead.

Comment: Thanks @code-jaff. Its working. I have updated the original question with a new test case using `axios`. **A question**, `is there a way to overcome the CORS policy`?. The error is: XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. Redirect from 'https://www.google.com/' to 'https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=l-8CWcW3OePQXvOvqJgB' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: hmm...OR maybe it is never possible to overcome the CORS policy via browser [Same-Origin-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)